How to decode the firestore exported XXX.overall_export_metadata file?
I am looking for a way to emulate firestore with multiple exported outputs. I am capable of starting an emulation (firebase emulators:start --import='pathToSingleExportOperation') just fine.
In firestore, you can either export all the database, or by selecting up to 60 collection groups (whitelist). I want to emulate my project leaving behind a couple of collection containing millions of records.  Emulating all the database is not an option for me because of the size of those collections.
Since there is no blacklist option for exporting the database I need to export all my valid collections in batches of 60, and then emulate those together.
I am capable of decoding the files with the extension .export_metadata.
I am thinking of

Decoding the files
Create a new structure with all the files of my export
Modify the necessary files (which I think it will be a kind of map pointing to the files exported) so I can merge everything
Encode again
Emulate

The problem is that protoc --decode_raw < XXX.overall_export_metadata is giving me Failed to parse input. And for what I have tried, this is the "master" file controlling what to look for in the import operation.
I have tried Searching for a way to export using a blacklist, which is not supported

IIRC overall_export_metadata files aren't protocol buffer files.

I've not ever tried to parse overall_export_metadata but, according to Firebase (sic.) Export format and metadata files, the files are LevelDB log format.
